# I am using TestNG with PowerMock..It always throws class not prepared for tests

Tags: java, testng, powermock

```
@PrepareForTest(DataAccessorFactory.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/test_jooq-spring.xml" })
public class WorkspaceManagerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {    

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {  
        this.applicationContext = SotsServiceLayerApplicationContext.getContext();
        ObjectInstancesFactory.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        PropertiesHandler.getInstance().loadPropertiesFile("app.properties");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void testgetAllWorkspaces()
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());

        try 
        {
            IDataAccessor ref = Mockito.mock(IDataAccessor.class);
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(DataAccessorFactory.class);
            Mockito.when(DataAccessorFactory.getInstance(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(ref);
            Mockito.when(ref.getAllWorkspaces(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(MockedDataModels.getWorkspaceList());

            queryparams.setExpand(Arrays.asList("sources","trainresults"));
            String output = workspaceManager.getAllWorkspaces(queryparams,mockURIInfo.constructMockURI(mockURIInfo,WorkspaceManager.class));

        }
        catch(Exception genEx)
        {
            genEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Always getting this exception

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@415a3f6a
The class com.klatencor.softs.dataaccessor.DataAccessorFactory not prepared for test.

    at org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.reporter.MockitoPowerMockReporter.classNotPrepared(MockitoPowerMockReporter.java:29)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockTypeValidatorFactory$DefaultMockTypeValidator.validate(MockTypeValidatorFactory.java:37)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.AbstractMockCreator.validateType(AbstractMockCreator.java:10)
    at org.powermock.api.mock
```

I have tried adding the `ObjectFactory in suite.xml` and overridden method... 
After adding the @objectFactory annotation method also, it fails with exception to create an instance of the test method
Nothing works...can someone please help to resolve this

Comment: I thought @RunWith() is a junit annotation... Is it a valid testng annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `PowerMockTestCase`

Like this:

```
@PrepareForTest(DataAccessorFactory.class)
public class WorkspaceManagerTest extends PowerMockTestCase { }
```